# Notification in PhoneGap for iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, cordova

I need to use on notification in **PhoneGap** 2.2.0 for iOS.

I add to PhoneGap.plist -> plugin ->com.phonegap.notification (also try just notification) and it not work.

Here PhoneGap document: 
**[PhoneGap Notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification)**

The iOS not recognize the notification

Here my use in the notification:

```
   navigator.notification.confirm(
        'EXIT?',  // message
        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'Good-Bay',            // title
        'Cancle,OK'          // buttonLabels
    );
```

What I miss?

Comment: are you doing this in an iframe?

Comment: I think I can assume you are not working in an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem on version 2.2,

I downloaded the latest version of PhoneGap (2.3.0) and it worked ..

Answer (score 1):

Apache Cordova Documentation says,you need to add
following lines in ***App/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist***

```
<key>Plugins</key>
<dict>
    <key>Notification</key>
    <string>CDVNotification</string>
</dict>
```

and find a sample code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
        alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
    }

    function showConfirm() {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
             'EXIT?',  
              onConfirm,          
             'Good-Bay',          
             'Cancle,OK'          
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showConfirm(); return false;">Show Confirm</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this helped you.

Comment: I do not have App/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist

Comment: I not know where to put the plugin.. I have only white list: App/Supporting Files/PhoneGap.plist -> it is not an xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 function onConfirm()
 {}
  navigator.notification.alert(
    'EXIT?',                 // message
    onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Good-Bay',            // title
    'OK'                  // button
);
```