# iOS notification.alert() not working using Phonegap 2.3.0

Tags: ios, cordova, alert

I have a strange issue when attempting to use navigator.notification.alert() in Xcode 4.6 using Phonegap 2.3.0.

I have two files, index.html and other.html. Clicking 'Test the alert' from index.html triggers the alert as expected, however after dismissing the alert and then navigating to other.html, clicking 'Test the other alert' does not trigger the alert.

However, if you click 'Test the alert' two or more times on index.html before moving to the other.html, the alert will continue to function as expected. It's only after triggering the alert ONCE and changing pages that the alerts stop functioning all together.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function alertTest() {
                navigator.notification.alert('Testing', null, 'Alert Test', 'OK');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='other.html'>Move to other page</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="alertTest(); return false;">Test the alert</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

other.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function alertTest() {
                navigator.notification.alert('Testing', null, 'Alert Test', 'OK');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html">Go back</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="alertTest(); return false;">Test the alert</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this happens, as in my app I need to be able to trigger alerts on button presses on different pages, which is seemingly hit-and-miss in this example.

Any help or nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated!!

**UPDATE:**

This seems to only happen with iOS 6 and 6.1 simulators. When alerts don't pop up, pressing the home key and then opening the app again makes the missing alerts appear all at once.

This example also has the same behaviour: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

Can anyone confirm if this is just a simulator bug in the latest Xcode?

Comment: Can you add <!DOCTYPE html> as your doctype?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that was in my code just not posted above. Edited my original post above to reflect that.

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: Are you testing on iOS 5 or 6? After playing around, this only seems to be an issue with iOS 6/6.1 (at least with the simulator, can't test on actual device). Have you tried recreating using a simulator or a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem exists since Phonegap 2.2 also see:
[Notification in PhoneGap for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437061/notification-in-phonegap-for-ios)
Same problem on WindowsMobile on Phonegap 2.3.

I didn't update from 2.1 ... seems to be the last version where it worked properly.

Don't forget to add `document.addEventlistener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);` above.

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest version of phonegap (2.4.0). Seems to resolve the problem. At least for me everything works normally now.