# PhoneGap Notification.Alert not working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Okay I've been working on this issue for a while now and can't figure this thing out. Simple PhoneGap test app, trying to show an alert.

**Using Cordova 2.9.0 for iOS**. I've added some simple test code and tested it in chrome to see where it breaks, because it isn't working in the emulator

When I test in the Chrome (of course same result in emulator, but no error message is showing)

- It executes the onDeviceReady as it should
- It sets tb2 textbox value to 'before alert'
- Then it breaks with the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined, on this line: navigator.notification.alert(...

It should be referencing the cordova.js properly, here is the structure of my app folder:

- cordova_plugins.js
- cordova.js
- /spec
- spec.html
- config.xml
- /css
- home.html
- /img
- index.html
- /js
- /res

Here is my config.xml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.blahblahblah.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello World</name>
    <description>
        Test blahblahblah Application
    </description>
    <author email="blahblahblah@blahblahblah.com" href="http://blahblahblah.com">
        blahblahblah
    </author>
    <access origin="*" />

    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />

    <plugins>
        <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

Here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
        document.getElementById('tb1').value = 'device ready';
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function showAlert() {
        document.getElementById('tb2').value = 'before alert';

        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
        document.getElementById('tb3').value = 'after alert';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
    <input type="text" id="tb1" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="tb2" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="tb3" value="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I have searched documentation, and haven't found any clue of why this isn't working, most answers to this question don't address version 2.9.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same Problem, searched a bit and found this:
[iOS Notification alert not Working - Phonegap 2.3.0][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730693/ios-notification-alert-not-working-using-phonegap-2-3-0

Answer (score 10):

I know the question is about Phonegap 2.9, but that's the first thing Google spits when somebody looks for "phonegap alert not working". So here's what I did for it to work with Phonegap 3.0:

According to the [manual](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface), you need to add the plugin to your project. Just navigate to your project root folder and write this command:

`$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git`

After that, I added this to my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    function onDeviceReady() {

        navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working", function(){}, "", "");
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: @Andre I tried the above answer,in my projecrt root directory i run the above command but i am getting the below error "-bash: phonegap: command not found".Any idea what could be te problem.

Comment: @user2086641 You either didn't install phonegap or it isn't in your path. Check out the website for installation instructions.

Comment: cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.dialogs - This also adds dialogs plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Phonegap 2.9.0 and the problem that i had is that I haven't add the script **cordova.js** to the page.

Also be aware that exist a cordova.js file specific to each platform so watch out of adding cordova.js from android on iOS.

Remember that all calls to the phonegap API should be done after **deviceready** has fired

Answer (score 0):

try to add this feature to your config.xml file..

```
 <feature name="Notification">
  <param name="wp-package" value="Notification"/>
 </feature>
```

..I hope that's help...

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add the plugin:

```
cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Then use the alert function which will interrupt program flow:

```
alert("some problem here");
```

Works for iOS and Android.