# Alert view displaying wrong title

Tags: iphone, ios5, cordova

Hi i'm using phone gap for developing an application.when i'm displaying an alert i'm doing alert("download complete") in html page. but it is displaying title as index.html. can any one please help me from this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the `notification`. Please call it after `deviceready`.

Please refer here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Add this on config.xml

```
<feature name="Notification">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification"/>
</feature>
```

Then, instead of calling `alert();` use the code below.

```
    navigator.notification.alert(
            "This is a message.",  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Error!',            // title
            'OK'                  // buttonName
        );


 function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: i can't get it clearly.Where i have to change can u please explain me in detail.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not working.when i'm inserting the code in the place of alert the html page is not loading.

Comment: Hey It's came Thank u so much.

Comment: @harish Oh great, but in case it does not work, this link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692348/phonegap-notification-alert-not-working