# navigator.notification.alert is not working in iOS 9

Tags: html, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ios9

I have used `navigator.notification.alert/navigator.connection.type` in my iOS Cordova based application.This is working perfectly with iOS 8.4 and below versions but not in iOS 9.

I have installed "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" and "**cordova-plugin-network-information**" with **Apache Cordova native platform version 3.8.0**

I have even this : [PhoneGap Notification.Alert not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692348/phonegap-notification-alert-not-working)

My header scripts which I have included in My app.

```
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script src="js/staticCalls.js"></script>
      <script src="js/dateFormat.js"></script>
      <script src="js/hashmap.js"></script>
      <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
     if(ValidateEmail(jsonData.email) == false)
     {
        // this line is not executing
        navigator.notification.alert("Please enter valid email address") ;$("#your_mail").focus();
    }
```

Comment: remove the cordova2.9.js

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have removed this ..But still the same problem

Comment: remove org.apache.cordova.dialogs and add cordova-plugin-dialogs

Comment: @jcesarmobile  thank you ..My issue is resolved with your suggestion... Even removed <script src="js/dateFormat.js"></script>
      <script src="js/hashmap.js"></script>,
      <script src="js/cordova2.9.js"></script>,<script src="js/popup.js"></script>..It is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution

As @jcesarmobile Suggested

```
 remove org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

and updating new plugin using

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Solved my issue in iOS 9